# EF Code first doesn't create new DB

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need your help! I'm working in Visual Studio 2010, when trying to generate a brand new SQLEXPRESS DB with the help of EF CodeFirst there are no any errors but there is no new autogenerated DB. What may be wrong? I'm writing data model classes, then I add a DBContext class, and writing logic to create a new DataBaseEntry, then I'm starting debug and no DB is generated

Answer (score 0):

Databases in EF-Code First are automatically generated (no need to create a DatabaseEntry) when you first access the data (nothing is done before a query is sent..)

You can also create a seed class by inheriting from DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges or DropCreateDatabaseAlways (names are self-explaining ), and implementing the Seed method.

You then have to set this class as an initializer :

```
  Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MySeedClass())
```

The first time EF will try to access your database, your seed class will be called ( if needed)

More here : http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm